# What is the difference between explicit and implicit JOIN in JPA? (performance)

Tags: java, jpa, jpa-2.0, jpql

These days I'm reading about `JPA`. I've learned that it is possible to use `explicit`or `implicit` `JOIN` in JPQL.

**Explicit join**

> em.createQuery(“SELECT b.title, p.name FROM Book b JOIN b.publisher
>   p”).getResultList();

**Implicit join**

> em.createQuery(“SELECT b.title, b.publisher.name FROM Book
>   b”).getResultList();

The source of these examples: [link](https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/query-complex-jpa-hibernate/)

**My question is:** Is there any difference in terms of performance between `explicit` and `implict` JOIN?

---

**UPDATE**

I've read what you've written @MatteoBaldi and @Kayaman, I've done some tests and I want to share the results with you.

I've created two entities: `students` and `course`, and I had a `manyToOne` (many students attend one course). I've used `EcpliseLink` Implementation of `JPA`.

Query = select students and dummyFiled from course, scenarios of execution:

1. manyToOne (defaultFetch -> eager), implicit JOIN. **Result:** a single SQL query that does all the work.
2. manyToOne (Fetch - > lazy), implicit JOIN. **Result:** the same SQL query as 1.
3. manyToOne (defaultFetch - > eager), explicit JOIN. **Result:** the same SQL query as 1.
4. manyToOne (Fetch - > lazy), explicit JOIN. **Result:** the same SQL query as 1.

So in my environement of test (EclipseLink,..) I had the same SQL query that  was generated from my JPQL queries. So I can say that the performance will be same (ofcourse, I say again in my conditions of tests, I hope that someone can confirm/correct my results and make a general rule.

Comment: Here you're selecting individual object properties which is not really a true use case of JPQL, it becomes interesting when you select entire object models - especially if they nest several levels deep. Then nullable state, lazy fetching and joining can start to make a difference in how things are queried and populated and how many queries will eventually be fired to the database to get the work done.

Answer (score 2):

They are parsed differently, so they can end up as different SQL queries depending on the query, entity relationships and other such things. Ideally there should be no difference as long as the JPQL queries are doing the same thing, but [it doesn't always work that way](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-7707).

The recommended way is to use explicit joins, and that has other advantages such as specifying `JOIN FETCH` on lazy relationships. This question concentrates a bit too much on performance, as obviously if one of them were more performant but gave the same results, there would be no reason to use the slower one.

Enabling SQL logging to see the generated queries is a good way to verify that your application is making the queries you expect, no matter which syntax you use. You can't just rely on the JPQL, you need to know and understand your database so you're not just using an "obfuscation layer" as a_horse_with_no_name likes to call ORM frameworks ;)

Comment: In the 3rd paragraph you adviced me to enable SQL logging and see. I've done that and I've updated my question it would be  nice of you if you check it  =)

Comment: @ziMtyth but there isn't a general rule except recommending explicit joins. They **should** be equivalent, but you must **always** check the actual queries (and perhaps making a bug report if the outcome isn't what would be expected).

Answer (score 2):

Usually, I always explicit every `JOIN`. The main objective is to be more clear about what the query are doing and how, having a more predictable SQL with future changes on the query.

But I can give you an example where the implicit JOIN have **more performance** than a explicit JOIN, even this gain of performance is very tiny in most of the cases and, personally, not pays the risk (I will explain what risk later).

Imagine that you are trying to group all books with the same publisher. With **explicit** JOIN, this is the JPQL:

```
 SELECT count(publisher.id) 
 FROM FROM Book b
 JOIN b.publisher publisher
 WHERE publisher.id = 1
 GROUP by publisher.id
```

This query is readable, without any repetition and any change in this query (like add another `WHERE` condition) will maintain the generated SQL as expected.

Now, with **implicit** JOIN:

```
 SELECT count(b.publisher.id) 
 FROM FROM Book b
 WHERE b.publisher.id = 1
 GROUP by b.publisher.id
```

We have `by b.publisher.id` repeated three times. If you add another condition, there is a risk that the JPQ interpretation from Hibernate change the generated SQL, doing unnecessary JOIN like explained on [Kayaman answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49516341/2387977).

But this JPQL with implicit JOIN don't do a extra `JOIN` to `publisher` table on the generated SQL, because he can use the `id` from `published_id`:

```
 SELECT Count(b.published_id) AS col_0_0_ 
 FROM   Book b
 WHERE  b.published_id = ? 
 GROUP  BY b.published_id
```

And the SQL explicit JOIN with an extra `JOIN`:

```
 SELECT Count(published.id) AS col_0_0_ 
 FROM   Book b
 INNER JOIN published published1_ 
           ON b.published_id = published1_.id 
 WHERE  published_id = ? 
 GROUP  BY published_id
```

But this only happens if the foreign key from `publisher` is in the `book` side. In this case is the right approach, but there are some mapping where the foreign key could be in any side of the table, so the explicit and implicit JPQLs queries can generate the **same** SQL.

And at my experience, explicit JOIN is always a better choice. The Hibernate does not always understand that the same implicit JOIN duplicated on the same query is part of the same `JOIN`, creating not optimized/weird SQLs.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your experience @Dherik. I will take it in consideration in the futur.

Comment: Interesting insight. With the right RDBMS, [join elimination](https://blog.jooq.org/2017/09/01/join-elimination-an-essential-optimiser-feature-for-advanced-sql-usage/) will kick in and eliminate the unnecessary join on the database level. E.g. in Oracle, SQL Server, Db2, both queries will still perform the same way if a foreign key is present on the relevant column.

Answer (score 1):

They *should* be the same but in reality it depends mainly on the underlying database. A quick way to test the performance in your current environment is to enable SQL logging, trace the native queries your `jpql` is traslated into and try those directly with a SQL client.

Comment: Why would it depend on the *database*? If JPA parses them both into the same query there's no difference. So the question is, does JPA always parse them to the same query or not.

Comment: Because your jpa implementation use the SQL dialect you have defined to translate those queries.

Comment: The dialect is still part of the JPA implementation, not the database. The dialect also doesn't have much to say about JPQL in general. It becomes relevant when translating the query to database specific syntax, at which point the general structure of joins etc. should already be done.

Comment: Are you saying that the same jpql query will have the same performance on an Oracle db and a MySQL db (just took these as examples)? If you need to compare the performance you have to get the native queries and try those on the field.

Comment: Of course not, we're not comparing different databases. We're comparing those two JPQL queries and whether they end up as same SQL queries. That's determined by the JPA implementation. If you look at the contents of the dialect classes you'll notice that they contain simple syntax mapping, nothing to do with joins or anything that would affect the structure of the query. So we're back to the start; does JPA *always* create the same query for those two JPQL queries, considering things like lazy mapping etc.

Comment: Well, even in that case of identical entities/jpa implementation/generated native queries (uhm, will be the query order the same in the two different cases?) the only way to compare the performance is to try directly the native queries.

Comment: What query order? Do you really think that JPQL will generate more than one query (barring eagerly initialized relationships and even then the order would be the same)? You're missing the big picture here, it's not really about performance. It's about whether this is just a difference in JPQL syntax or not. But no use continuing this in comments, I'll take a look at the syntax parsing later.

Comment: In this example, no, but the question is: "Is there any difference in terms of performance between explicit and implict JOIN?". It's impossible generalize about explicit/implicit join query behaviour ABOUT PERFORMANCE (that's what the question was about) without defining a specific database and directly trying the queries. The rest is just speculation.